# Non-Abelian vertex 3-gauge-boson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, feynman-diagrams, yang-mills

I am trying to understand how the vertices depicted in page 507 of Peskin and Schroeder come about. I understand that vertex where we have 1 gauge boson and two fermions but I'm confused on the indices used on the 3-vertex and 4-vertex interaction.

Then in (16.8) they write down one of the possible combinations which would be
$$-igf^{abc}(-ik^\nu)g^{\mu\rho}.\tag{16.8}$$

I understand the prefactor and that the derivative part gives the $(-ik)$ term (if the momentum flows in) but how do we chose the metric indices?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "how do we chose the metric indices"? Do you understand why we expect this term to have 3 spacetime indices and 3 group indices?

Comment: Upon further study, I realised there are 6 possible contractions of the 3-vertex term, which basically give the term we wanted. I am trying to figure out the 4-vertex now.

Answer (score 3):

1. Briefly speaking, the Feynman rule in position space for the cubic gluon vertex (16.8) follows from the cubic gluon field term in the Lagrangian density (times $i$)
   $$\begin{align} i{\cal L}_3~=~&-igf^{abc}(\partial_{\kappa}A^a_{\lambda}) A^{\kappa b}A^{\lambda c}\cr~=~&-igf^{abc}g^{\mu\rho}(\partial^{\nu}A^a_{\mu}) A^b_{\nu}A^c_{\rho},\end{align} \tag{16.6}$$
2. The derivative $\partial^{\nu}$ becomes $-ik^{\nu}$ by Fourier transformation:
   $$\begin{align} iS_3~=~& i\int\!d^4x~{\cal L}_3
   ~\stackrel{(16.6)}{=}~\ldots\cr
   ~=~&-igf^{abc}g^{\mu\rho}\int\! \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\int\! \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\int\! \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \cr 
   &\times (2\pi)^4\delta^4(k\!+\!p\!+\!q) (-ik^{\nu})\widetilde{A}^a_{\mu}(k)\widetilde{A}^b_{\nu}(p)\widetilde{A}^c_{\rho}(q).\end{align} $$
   From the Dirac delta function we learn that each vertex obeys momentum conservation.
3. The full cubic gluon vertex Feynman rule in momentum space involves a symmetrization of the 3 legs, i.e. it has 3!=6 terms, cf. Fig. 16.1.

References:

1. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT.* 1995; p. 507.